# Angular: No overload matches this call errors

Tags: angular, observable

I have the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const SERVICE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/';

@Injectable()

export class BackendService {

  constructor(private client: HttpClient) { }
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
...
getUser(firstname): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}/user/firstname/${firstname}`;
    return this.client.get(API_URL, { headers: this.httpOptions }).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {}
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
...
```

I get the following errors:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Property 'headers' is incompatible with index signature.
          Type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'.
            Type 'HttpHeaders' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<unknown>) => never): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T>(operation?: string, result?: T) => (error: any) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<unknown>) => never'.
      Type '(error: any) => Observable<Observable<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(selector: (err: any, caught: Observable<unknown>) => ObservableInput<unknown>): OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T>(operation?: string, result?: T) => (error: any) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<unknown>) => ObservableInput<unknown>'.
      Type '(error: any) => Observable<Observable<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<unknown>'.
        Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '(error: any) => Observable<Observable<unknown>>' but required in type 'Iterable<unknown>'.
```

I have set the header as you can see above. I tried settings the headers manually without any avail. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the import statements in the BackendService as well?

Comment: @Apokralipsa done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the `HttpOptions` to the `get` method which can have an instance of `HttpHeaders` in the `headers` field. Instead you are wrapping it twice. If you `JSON.stringify` the object you are passing you would get something similiar to :

```
{
    "headers" : {
        "headers" : {
            // your headers here
        }
    }
}
```

In the getUser method switch to something like:

```
getUser(firstname): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}/user/firstname/${firstname}`;
    return this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).pipe(
        map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {}
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
    )
}
```

Your `httpOptions` already has the correct type.